# How to concatenate videos using FFMPEG in android using guardian project

Tags: java, android, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to combine two mp4 videos using **guardian project** as library project in my app. But it does not generate the output at specified location. I went through various solution for it but no success. 
PFB the code :

```
File fileTmp = this.getCacheDir(); 
File fileAppRoot = new File(this.getApplicationInfo().dataDir);

FfmpegController fc;

fc = new FfmpegController(fileTmp, fileAppRoot);



    final Clip out = new Clip(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/Video/compiled.mp4");

    ArrayList<Clip> listVideos = new ArrayList<Clip>();

    File fileVideoRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/Video");
    String[] fileList = fileVideoRoot.list();

    for (String fileVideo : fileList)
    {
        if (fileVideo.endsWith("mp4"))
        {
            Clip clip = new Clip();
            clip.path = new File(fileVideoRoot,fileVideo).getCanonicalPath();

            fc.getInfo(clip);

            clip.duration = clip.duration-1;
            listVideos.add(clip);


        }
    }


    fc.concatAndTrimFilesMP4Stream(listVideos, out, false, false, new ShellUtils.ShellCallback() {

        @Override
        public void shellOut(String shellLine) {

            System.out.println("fc>" + shellLine);
        }

        @Override
        public void processComplete(int exitValue) {

            if (exitValue < 0)
                System.err.println("concat non-zero exit: " + exitValue);

        }
    });
```

I am getting exception :

> There was a problem rendering the video:
>   /mnt/sdcard/Download/Video/compiled.mp4

Please guide me on how to concatenate videos in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not an ffmpeg error from ffmpeg's stdout.

In order to figure out what is actually going on you will need to capture in the android layer, the STREAM=stdout AND the STREAM=stderr from the native 'processbuilder' or whatever you are using to get a shell from Android/java...

for example:

```
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            Map<String, String> environ = builder.environment();
//          for(Entry<String, String> entry : environ.entrySet()){
    //          System.out.println("ENV " +entry.getKey() + " " +entry.getValue());
      //      }
//          builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process process = null;
            try {
                process = builder.start();

            InputStream is = process.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
              //System.out.println(line);
                outfil=line;
            }

//          int exitVal = process.waitFor();
 //           System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
```

if you are testing with a rooted phone then you should just be able to use adb push to move the ffmpeg binary to /data/data/... and to invoke it directly.

You may be able to redirect stderr/stdout to a log file in conjunction with CLI tests.